# Gradle not generating a String with quotes

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to include a custom field in `BuildConfig` containing the build date using this function:

```
def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
    return formattedDate
}
```

Then, in defaultConfig I put:

```
buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_NUMBER", getDate()
```

Problem is, the field generated by Gradle is:

```
public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = 20141108114911;
```

which throws "Integer too large", but I don't want an Integer, I want a String!

I tried to explicitly replace the `def` with `String`, tried `getDate().toString`, `getDate() as String` and `"${getDate()}"`, and still no quote to surround my String. I also tried to put a character like "-" in the middle of the date, it stills doesn't generate quotes, making:

```
public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = 20141108-114911;
```

clearly not making any sense...

I am out of idea here, not being familiar enough with Groovy and so not sure if there's another (working) way to "enforce" a String.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to add escaped quotes:

```
buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_NUMBER", "\"${new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')}\""
```

Comment: or just put mixed quotes: `' "BuildID" '`

Comment: Dutch Masters is the real mvp

Comment: Mixing only works like this '/"BuildID\"', no gain.